# Can't edit anything in the WordPress admin panel after uploading the database to the hosting

Tags: php, wordpress, hosting

Sorry for my bad english :)
If you just upload WordPress to the hosting with an empty database, then everything is fine, but if I upload my database, then I can not do anything. Example on plugins: I cannot add or remove them, the buttons are static. On the local server in phpMyAdmin added a user, but nothing changed. I use the same WP login and password, both on local and on hosting (the same account)